# How to know what context data returned by any GCBV in django?

Tags: django, django-views

Is there any way to know the dictionary returned by any GCBV other than looking at the code.

[context_dict](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COoRg.png)

I had to look at the code at django.views.generic.list to know that ListView returns this context dictionary.
Is there any other fast way to know

Comment: Can you add more details to the question? What do you need to achieve?

Comment: You may find this resource helpful: http://ccbv.co.uk

Answer (score 0):

As per [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/), the default is `object_list`, but can be set using

```
context_object_name = 'your_context_name'
```

If you want to add some other context

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['your_other_context_name'] = Model.objects.all() # or whatever you want to query
    return context
```